# Cannot convert from 'SpecificComponent' to 'IComponent<IComponentGuid>'

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

I've this class structure:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public interface IComponentGuid { }

    class ComponentGuid : IComponentGuid{}

    internal interface IComponent<T> where T : IComponentGuid {
         List<T> List();
     }

    class SpecificComponent : IComponent<ComponentGuid> { 
      public List<ComponentGuid> List()
      {
          throw new System.NotImplementedException();
       }
    }

    class P
    {
        public P(IComponent<IComponentGuid> pComponent) { }
    }


    class Caller
    {
        public Caller()
        {
            var specific = new SpecificComponent();

            var p = new P(specific);
            }
    }
}
```

The problem arise instantiating P: var p = new P(specific);

I get a

```
cannot convert from 'ClassLibrary1.SpecificComponent' to 'ClassLibrary1.IComponent<ClassLibrary1.IComponentGuid>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work if you forgo `List<T>` on your interface and replace it with a co-variant interface of `IEnumerable<T>` and then make your type parameter co-variant as well:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public interface IComponentGuid { }

    class ComponentGuid : IComponentGuid{}

    internal interface IComponent<out T> where T : IComponentGuid {
         IEnumerable<T> List();
     }

    class SpecificComponent : IComponent<ComponentGuid> { 
      public IEnumerable<ComponentGuid> List()
      {
          throw new System.NotImplementedException();
       }
    }

    class P
    {
        public P(IComponent<IComponentGuid> pComponent) { }
    }


    class Caller
    {
        public Caller()
        {
            var specific = new SpecificComponent();

            var p = new P(specific);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `IReadOnlyList<T>` might be slightly better - allows some additional functionality like accessing items by index and item counts without iterating the list.

Comment: I'm not seeing a resolution for that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying this solution splitting the IComponent interface into two, one covariant and one invariant.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public interface IComponentGuid { }

    public class ComponentGuid : IComponentGuid { }

    public interface IComponentBase<out T> where T : IComponentGuid
    {
        IEnumerable<T> List();
    }

    interface IComponent<T>
    {
        void AddToList(T item );
    }

    public class SpecificComponent : IComponentBase<ComponentGuid>, IComponent<ComponentGuid>
    {
        public IEnumerable<ComponentGuid> List()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void AddToList(ComponentGuid item)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }


    public class P
    {
        public P(IComponentBase<IComponentGuid> pComponentBase) { }
    }


    class Caller
    {
        public Caller()
        {
            var specific = new SpecificComponent();

            var p = new P(specific);

        }
    }
}
```